# Apply the .map method to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array.prototype.map

There is an array of objects. I need to apply the .map method to it

```
const friends = [
{"id": 1, "name": "OLIVER", "age":"15"},
{"id": 2, "name": "JACK", "age":"17"},
{"id": 3, "name": "AMELIA", "age":"20"},
{"id": 4, "name": "AMELIA", "age":"23"},
{"id": 5, "name": "EMILY", "age":"25"},
]
```

Here is the option that I tried to make but failed:

```
render() {  
    return(
      <table className="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>     
      <th>id/th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     {friends.map(p =>
    <tr>   
      <td key={p.id}>{p.id}</td>
      <td key={p.id}>{p.Name}</td>
      <td key={p.id}>{p.Age}</td>
    </tr> 
)
}   
  </tbody>
</table>
)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what error you are facing ?

Comment: `Name` and `Age` are lowercase properties in your objects, so they should also be when you access them.

Comment: @Евгений Федосеев did it solve ?

Answer (score 2):

You are referencing wrong properties, should be "age","name". And may be just add the key to your parent element.

```
 <tr key={p.id}>   
      <td >{p.id}</td>
      <td>{p.name}</td>
      <td>{p.age}</td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Object keyes are case-sensitive in js, so `p.Name` is not a value in `friends` but `p.name` is.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong properties, should be in lowercase (equals friends definition), also left two parenthesis.

```
render() {  
    return(
      <table className="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>     
      <th>id/th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     {friends.map((p) => (
    <tr>   
      <td key={p.id}>{p.id}</td>
      <td key={p.id}>{p.name}</td>
      <td key={p.id}>{p.age}</td>
    </tr> 
))
}   
  </tbody>
</table>
)
}
```